# Is it poor practice to use very similar for loops in two places with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm generating two lists for a `roster`.

One list to show the current members of `that year`, and a second list if people have been `excused in that year`.

I noticed that I have two of the same for loops except one prints out all of the true Boolean values, and one the false. Is there a better way (or a method of some sort) to print out the people who are `excused and not excused`?

```
<h2>Roster {{year-1}}-{{year}}</h2>

<div *ngFor="let k of peoples">
  <div *ngFor="let a of k.people; let j = index">
    <div *ngIf="k.year == year && k.people[j].excused == false">
      {{k.people[j].firstName}} {{k.people[j].lastName}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Excused</h2>

<div *ngFor="let k of peoples">
  <div *ngFor="let a of k.people; let j = index">
    <div *ngIf="k.year == year && k.people[j].excused == true">
      {{k.people[j].firstName}} {{k.people[j].lastName}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create the arrays in the component (.ts) then you don't have nest the ngFor's

Comment: Please post the code as a text instead of an image.

Comment: Okay, it's been changed @scopchanov

Comment: On an unrelated note, I wouldn't use `== true` or `== false`, because `k.people[j].excused` already evaluates to a boolean expression. You can simply use `k.people[j].excused` or `!k.people[j].excused`

Comment: @ShamPooSham I like that idea, thank you!

Comment: If you need to display people on 2 columns based ok excused value you can iterate once and put the name in a span tag with class "excused" or "not-excused" using ngClass. Then the wrapper div set css property to display grid, and grid-template-columns to 1fr 1fr. Then you can set for first class grid column 1 and 2nd class grid-column 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use it this way without additional *ngIf.

As mentioned in comments it would be better to prepare to separete arrays for data in the component and do it once after data updated. But since the context of usage is unknown this looks like a better solution. You need to avoid *ngIf if you can filter data in array to prevent from unnecessary work another structure directive in template. It always gives you perfomance advanateges.

In your **component** you can define `filter function`:

```
getExcused(isExcused: boolean) {
    return this.peoples
        .filter(k=>k.year === this.year)
        .map(k=>k.people)
        .filter(p=>p.excused === isExcused);
}
```

Then in template:

```
<h2>Roster {{year-1}}-{{year}}</h2>
<div *ngFor="let a of getExcused(false)">
    {{ a.firstName }} {{ a.lastName }}
</div>
<h2>Excused</h2>
<div *ngFor="let k of getExcused(true)">
    {{ k.firstName }} {{ k.lastName }}
</div>
```

If your component uses change detection strategy on push it won't make any perfomance issues.

Comment: Is this inside the second for loop?

Comment: Sorry, there were some issues in my previous answer, i'v updated it with propper one.

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution, but I keep getting errors. There's an extra *ngFor which i fixed, but i'm still getting an error. Do I have to import .filter anywhere? I've never used that before. It keeps saying "Binding cannot contain assignments" in the console log errors.

Comment: Can I get excused by you? Unfortunatly you can't use filter right in *ngFor structure directive. It was my misstake. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'am wrong, but isn't a pipe the prefered way of doing this ? Or better, you could chain 2 pipes !

```
<div *ngFor="let k of peoples| yearPipe: year | excusedPipe: no">

      {{k.people[j].firstName}} {{k.people[j].lastName}}

</div>

<h2>Excused</h2>

<div *ngFor="let k of peoples| yearPipe: year | excusedPipe: yes">

      {{k.people[j].firstName}} {{k.people[j].lastName}}

</div>

@Pipe({ name: 'yearPipe' })
export class YearPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allPeople: People[], year: string) {
    return allPeople.filter(person => person.year == parseInt(year));
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'excusedPipe' })
export class ExcusedPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allPeople: People[], excused: string) {
    if (excused === 'yes'){
       return allPeople.filter(person => person.excused);
    }else{
       return allPeople.filter(person => !person.excused);
    }
  }
}
```

The only tricky part is that the parameter to the pipe is allways string, or that is what I find in docs in Angular.io

Edit : refer to this stackblitz example ( Chained Pipes example ): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you how you want to structure your code, but if you want to avoid this, you could do something like this

**html**

```
<div *ngfor="let exused of isExcused(true)">
  {{excused.firstName}} {{excused.lastName}}
</div>

<div *ngfor="let exused of isExcused(false)">
  {{excused.firstName}} {{excused.lastName}}
</div>
```

**ts**

```
isExcused(excused) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.peoples.length; i++) {
    if(peoples[i].year === this.year) { // it's better to have this check here
      for (let j = 0; j < this.peoples[i]people.length; j++) {
        if (peoples[i].people[j].excused === excused) {
          arr.push(peoples[i].people[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

But this is a very ugly solution. You should do something like this:

**html**

```
<div *ngfor="let exused of excusedList">
  {{excused.firstName}} {{excused.lastName}}
</div>

<div *ngfor="let unexcused of unexcusedList">
  {{unexcused.firstName}} {{unexcused.lastName}}
</div>
```

**ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.excusedList = isExcused(true);
  this.unexcusedList = isExcused(false);
}
```

because it looks like your lists wont be updated on the fly. Also, you could use something `.forEach()` or `.filter` instead of for loops to help make the code not look so blocky.

Comment: _"But this is a very ugly solution. You should do something like this"_ Then why do you present the "ugly" version?

Comment: because it is reflects more closely to what the poster wanted, an html solution that is updated on every digest cycle. I don't know where/how often the lists are updated, so I offered a more optimal solution that may not work because of how little we know about how the user interacts with the data.